# Is it correct to say "take me on the way"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I want to express that I learning some courses will give me a good vision in a specific field.

Can I say like "these courses take me on the way to the statistics"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to say

> These courses should/will get me started on my way to learning/understanding statistics.

We can shorten this in several ways.

> These should get me on my way

would be clear and idiomatic if your listener knows what you are talking about.

The sense of *way* here, means *heading toward* or *going in the direction of* some destination. We can assume that the destination you have in mind is the mastery of statistics to some degree.

See http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+way

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not correct.

I assume the course is about statistics, right? Maybe you could say,

> This course will give a good overview of statistics.

An "overview" means you will understand what the subject is about, but not be an expert. I'm not sure if that's what you want to say.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to express "to be an expert", how could I say?

Comment: Maybe "This course will give you a solid understanding of statistics."

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not idiomatic to say:

These courses will take me on the way to the statistics.

I think you can rephrase your sentence as follows:

These courses will go a long way toward(s) learning statistics.

These courses will give a good insight into statistics.

Comment: The courses won't go anywhere. We could use something like *Taking these courses will go a long way . . . .*